# Create toggle button in Fomantic with preview on hover appearance

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, fomantic-ui

### Disclaimer

I asked a similar question (which I deleted because it lacked some clarity, so I give it a new try).

### Framework

I am developing a R / Shiny app. That is, I create most of my web interface using R libraries. One of this libraries is [`shiny.semantic`](https://github.com/Appsilon/shiny.semantic) through which I can use a pre-processed Fomantic CSS / JS bundle (Version 2.8.3).

Theoretically, I could of course also link versus the newest version of the Fomantic framework (or a customized version), but as the system I will install the app on has only limited internet access, I want to rely as much as possible on R packaged libraries (which are easy to install on the system) and keep the footprint of my package low that is do not ship my own version of Fomantic.

That means, I also have to live with the defaults the R package authors have chosen for their preprocessed CSS / JS (which from all I can judge are the factory defaults).

Having said that, my problem at hand has nothing to do with R (except that I cannot easily swap out the given Fomantic dependency), as I can create any HTML I like and thus, my problem is indeed an HTML/CSS/JS problem.

### Goal

I want to have a button:

1. Which has an disabled look and feel upon loading (`opacity: .45`)
2. When hovering changes its color (adding class `.teal`) and opacity back to 1.
3. When clicked keep the color class `.teal` and opacity 1.
4. Now, when hovering the color should change back to no color (i.e. removing `.teal`) and opacity to `.45`.

That is the button has basically 2 states which the button should change on click. And the hover effect is kind of a preview what will happen, once we will click the button.

### My try

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".button").on({
    click: function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("is-active");
      $(this).addClass("clicked");
      $(this).off("mouseleave");
      $(this).one("mouseleave", function () {
        $(this).removeClass("clicked");
      });
    },
    mouseenter: function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("teal", !$(this).hasClass("is-active"));
      $(this).one("mouseleave", function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("teal", $(this).hasClass("is-active"));
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.button.is-active:not(:hover), .button:not(.is-active):hover:not(.clicked) {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.button.is-active:hover:not(.clicked), .button:not(.is-active) {
  opacity: 0.45 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.8.3/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fomantic-ui@2.8.3/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="ui icon button">
<i class="less than equal icon"></i>
</button>
```

### Issues

This seems to be rather over engineered. With the given restrictions (a pre-processed Fomantic framework) and the wish not to hard code the color in the CSS, is there a more "canonical" solution? How would a trained frontend developer solve this issue (given that they cannot customize the CSS/JS)?